# Service builder is unable to delete its jar file while building

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, liferay, subclipse

I am developing a Liferay portlet project under Eclipse Helios. A project is connected to subversion.

When I run "build services" submenu in Liferay menu, I get error at last stages of building, saying

```
build-common-plugin.xml:208: Unable to delete file ...-portlet-service.jar
```

I suspect subversion is locking this file. I can't delete this file from file manager too, until Eclipse is running. I can build services only if I exit Eclipse and delete this jar manually.

How to ask subversion not lock files? I am using Subclipse 1.8.2.

Comment: you sure it's subversion and not windows?  windows likes to lock files that are in use?  (are you on windows)?

Comment: Not I am not sure this is subversion, just suspect it because had no this error untill turned to it. Yes, I am in windows. But why this jar should be in use when I do nothing with it?

Answer (score 1):

Subversion does not put file system locks on files, but if you are on Windows any file will be locked while it is being read or executed.  When I see a JAR file unable to be deleted, my first instinct is to think it is in use by a running Java application.  Are you running your web app in a web container that is still running?